# Excel Formula / Excel-Macro / Duplicate data

Tags: vba, excel

Good day, badly need help regarding a certain excel lookup/return value. I tried INDEX/MATCH, VLOOKUP, and VBA but all of them failed since I'm not really familiar with those.

[image]
Problem is this.

The lookup value will be the productID and ContractID and Type of Change. In this case it is  "delete" which has multiple values. I'd like to return the values in column Old Value based on the latest date on Valid From column. Therefore,

LOOKUP VALUE
- product id
- contract id
- type of change

then criteria for choosing the multiple results would be latest date from valid from. Please do help. Best Regards.

Comment: Does your data change frequently? If not, we can sort it (or create a sorted copy somewhere), then find the first match when queried for some criteria.

Comment: yes it changes frequently. the "delete" part can be 10 items on one file. that's why I am having a hard time

Comment: It looks easy to do with a VBA loop routine, but I'm afraid it should be too slow if the data set is large

Comment: Please do help me with the VBA code. Not really good with it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work? not sure, you can try it out see whether it does:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=123456)*(B:B="SGSINtest")*(C:C="delete")*(D:D=MAX(IF(AND(A:A=123456,B:B="SGSINtest,C:C=""delete"),D:D)))*(E:E))
```

where column A represents the product Id
column B represents the id and
column C represents type and
D represents the date Valid from
E represents OldValue?

Comment: There is no guarantee that each of these ranges will have the same size. It is most often not the case. It will almost always show #N/A, but interesting though.

Comment: I tried yours and modified it a little but isince the B:B="" is specified its a little hard.

Comment: you can substitue "SGSINtest" with whatever the ID is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (very basic) macro that should give you somehow what you are looking for, but beware that it is not optimized, might be very slow on large data, and moreover it supposes that the date columns are formatted as date types. Given the criteria, it gives you the row (as Range object) that matches the criteria and has the highest date if more than one row do. If no row matches the criteria, it return "Nothing".

```
Function rowWithHighestVF(productId As Long, contractId As String, typeOfChange As String) As Range
    Dim r As Range, validFrom As Date, maxVF As Date: maxVF = 0
    For Each r In UsedRange.Rows
        If r.Cells(1) = productId And r.Cells(2) = contractId And r.Cells(3) = typeOfChange Then
            validFrom = r.Cells(4)
            If validFrom > maxVF Then
               maxVF = validFrom 
               Set rowWithHighestVF = r
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not rowWithHighestVF Is nothing then rowWithHighestVF.Activate
End Function
```

This is the starting point. Make it work on your data and then try to optimize it. Hope it helps.

Comment: ill try this first and get back to you